# TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, join

Estoy intentando implementar un join entre 3 tablas usando JPA, pero cada vez que ejecuto el código obtengo la siguiente traza de error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class com.santander.historicaladdress.entity.HisDomCompUkEntity. Expected: class com.santander.historicaladdress.entity.HisDomCompUkPk, got class com.santander.historicaladdress.entity.HisDomicIntPk
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.checkIdClass(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:166) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:86) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1129) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1022) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:639) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:431) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:154) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1133) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:992) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:930) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2617) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2600) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2429) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2424) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:501) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:371) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1326) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:606) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:529) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
... 97 common frames omitted
```

El código que estoy utilizando es el siguiente:
**ENTIDAD RELTIPDOMHIS**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "REL_TIP_DOM_HIS")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode

public class RelTipDomHisEntity {

    @EmbeddedId
    private RelTipDomHisPk pk;

    @Size(min = 10, max = 10)
    @Column(name = "E0712_FECH_FIN", nullable = false)
    private Date fechFin;

    @Size(min = 9, max = 9)
    @Column(name = "E0712_NRODOM", nullable = false)
    private Integer nroDom;

    @Size(min = 8, max = 8)
    @Column(name = "E0712_USULTACT", nullable = false)
    private String usultAct;

    @Size(min = 4, max = 4)
    @Column(name = "E0712_EMULTACT", nullable = false)
    private String multAct;

    @Size(min = 4, max = 4)
    @Column(name = "E0712_CEULTACT", nullable = false)
    private String ceultAct;

    @Size(min = 10, max = 10)
    @Column(name = "E0712_FEULTACT", nullable = false)
    private Date feultAct;

    @Size(min = 8, max = 8)
    @Column(name = "E0712_HOR_ULTA", nullable = false)
    private Time horUlta;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 26, max = 26)
    @Column(name = "E0712_TIMALTA", nullable = false)
    private Timestamp timAlta;


    /* Foreign key for HIS_DOMIC_INT table */
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "E0712_TIPO_PER", referencedColumnName = "E0711_TIPO_PER", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "E0712_COD_PERS", referencedColumnName = "E0711_COD_PERS", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "E0712_NRODOM", referencedColumnName = "E0711_NRODOM", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "E0712_FECH_INI", referencedColumnName = "E0711_FECH_INI", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private HisDomicIntEntity hisDomicInt;
}
```

**CLAVE PRIMARIA PARA ENTIDAD RELTIPDOMHIS**

```
@Embeddable
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode

public class RelTipDomHisPk implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6181758689752518382L;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 1)
    @Column(name = "E0712_TIPO_PER", nullable = false)
    private String tipoPers;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 9, max = 9)
    @Column(name = "E0712_COD_PERS", nullable = false)
    private Integer codPers;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2, max = 2)
    @Column(name = "E0712_TIPODOM", nullable = false)
    private Integer tipoDom;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 10, max = 10)
    @Column(name = "E0712_FECH_INI", nullable = false)
    private Date fechIni;
}
```

**ENTIDAD HISDOMCOMPUK**

```
@Table(name = "HIS_DOM_COMP_UK")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class HisDomCompUkEntity {


    @EmbeddedId
    private HisDomCompUkPk pk;

    @Size(min = 10, max = 10)
    @Column(name = "E0497_FECH_FIN", nullable = false)
    private Timestamp fechFin;


    @Size(min = 2, max = 2)
    @Column(name = "E0497_CAL_DOM", nullable = false)
    private String calDom;

    @Size(min = 18, max = 18)
    @Column(name = "E0497_MATCKPRT", nullable = false)
    private String matckprt;

    @Size(min = 2, max = 2)
    @Column(name = "E0497_INFSRCTP", nullable = false)
    private String infsrctp;

    @Size(min = 2, max = 2)
    @Column(name = "E0497_TIPBUZON", nullable = false)
    private String tipBuzon;

    @Size(min = 10, max = 10)
    @Column(name = "E0497_FEC_EFEC", nullable = false)
    private Date fecEfec;

    @Size(min = 4, max = 4)
    @Column(name = "E0497_DETAL_CP", nullable = false)
    private String detalCp;

    @Size(min = 8, max = 8)
    @Column(name = "E0497_USULTACT", nullable = false)
    private String usultact;

    @Size(min = 4, max = 4)
    @Column(name = "E0497_EMULTACT", nullable = true)
    private String emultact;

    @Size(min = 4, max = 4)
    @Column(name = "E0497_CEULTACT", nullable = true)
    private String ceultact;

    @Size(min = 10, max = 10)
    @Column(name = "E0497_FEULTACT", nullable = true)
    private Date feultact;

    @Size(min = 8, max = 8)
    @Column(name = "E0497_HOR_ULTA", nullable = true)
    private Time horulta;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 26, max = 26)
    @Column(name = "E0497_TIMALTA", nullable = false)
    private Timestamp timAlta;

    /* Foreign key for HIS_DOMIC_INT table */   
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "E0497_TIPO_PER", referencedColumnName = "E0711_TIPO_PER", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "E0497_COD_PERS", referencedColumnName = "E0711_COD_PERS", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "E0497_NRODOM", referencedColumnName = "E0711_NRODOM", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "E0497_FECH_INI", referencedColumnName = "E0711_FECH_INI", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private HisDomicIntEntity hisDomicInt;
}
```

**CLAVE PRIMARIA PARA HISDOMCOMPUK**

```
@Embeddable
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class HisDomCompUkPk implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 1)
    @Column(name = "E0497_TIPO_PER", nullable = false)
    private String tipoPers;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 9, max = 9)
    @Column(name = "E0497_COD_PERS", nullable = false)
    private Integer codPers;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 10, max = 10)
    @Column(name = "E0497_NRODOM", nullable = false)
    private Integer nroDom; 

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 1)
    @Column(name = "E0497_FECH_INI", nullable = false)
    private Date fechIni;
}
```

**ENTIDAD HISDOMICENTITY**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "HIS_DOMIC_INT")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class HisDomicIntEntity {


    @EmbeddedId
    private HisDomicIntPk pk;

    @Size(min = 10, max = 10)
    @Column(name = "E0711_FECH_FIN", nullable = false)
    private Timestamp fechFin;


    @Size(min = 2, max = 2)
    @Column(name = "E0711_FMTO_DOM", nullable = false)
    private String fmtoDom;

    @Size(min = 2, max = 2)
    @Column(name = "E0711_COD_PAIS", nullable = false)
    private String codPais;

    @Size(min = 8, max = 8)
    @Column(name = "E0711_USULTACT", nullable = false)
    private String usultAct;

    @Size(min = 4, max = 4)
    @Column(name = "E0711_EMULTACT", nullable = false)
    private String emultAct;

    @Size(min = 4, max = 4)
    @Column(name = "E0711_CEULTACT", nullable = false)
    private String ceultAct;

    @Size(min = 10, max = 10)
    @Column(name = "E0711_FEULTACT", nullable = false)
    private Date feultAct;

    @Size(min = 8, max = 8)
    @Column(name = "E0711_HOR_ULTA", nullable = false)
    private Time horUlta;

    @Size(min = 280, max = 280)
    @Column(name = "E0711_DOM_DESC", nullable = true)
    private String domDesc;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 26, max = 26)
    @Column(name = "E0711_TIMALTA", nullable = false)
    private Timestamp timAlta;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="hisDomicInt")
    private RelTipDomHisEntity relTipDomHis;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="hisDomicInt")
    private HisDomCompUkEntity hisDomCompUk;
}
```

**CLAVE PRIMARIA PARA ENTIDAD HISDOMICINT**

```
@Embeddable
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode

public class HisDomicIntPk implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 1)
    @Column(name = "E0711_TIPO_PER", nullable = false)
    private String tipoPers;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 9, max = 9)
    @Column(name = "E0711_COD_PERS", nullable = false)
    private Integer codPers;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 9, max = 9)
    @Column(name = "E0711_NRODOM", nullable = false)
    private Integer nroDom;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 10, max = 10)
    @Column(name = "E0711_FECH_INI", nullable = false)
    private Date fechIni;
}
```

REPOSITORIO Y QUERY

```
@Query("select hdi from RelTipDomHisEntity rtdh inner join rtdh.hisDomicInt hdi inner join hdi.hisDomCompUk hdcu"
        + " where hdi.pk.codPers = :codPers")
public HisDomicIntEntity doJoin(@Param("codPers") Integer codPers);
```

Toda ayuda es bienvenida dado que soy nuevo en esto de JPA. He estado buscando por Internet pero no he conseguido nada que pueda ayudarme.

¡Muchas gracias de antemano a todos!

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la select debe de ser algo así:

```
"select rtdh from RelTipDomHisEntity rtdh join fetch rtdh.hisDomicInt hdint join fecth rtdh.hisDomCompUk hdcuk where hdcuk.pk.codPers = :codPers"
```

No estoy seguro de que la query funcione 100% lo que si te digo seguro es que para recuperar las entidades a las que se hace referencia en los joinColumns debes utilizar join fetch.

Tienes un ejemplo muy bueno aquí:
https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-multi-level-fetching/
donde te enseña un modelo de hoja->rama->arbol->bosque. La query que monta es 
`"select f " +
"from Forest f " +
"join fetch f.trees t " +
"join fetch t.branches b " +
"join fetch b.leaves l "`

Opcionalmente yo lo que haría seria evitar las claves compuestas, complican enormemente los joins entre tablas. Pero lo dicho esto solo es opcional. 
Si tienes posibilidad o ganas de cambialo yo haría  algo parecido a esto:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Table(name = "HIS_DOM_COMP_UK", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"E0497_TIPO_PER",  "E0497_COD_PERS", "E0497_NRODOM", "E0497_FECH_INI"}) })
public class HisDomCompUkEntity {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 1)
    @Column(name = "E0497_TIPO_PER", nullable = false)
    private String tipoPers;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 9, max = 9)
    @Column(name = "E0497_COD_PERS", nullable = false)
    private Integer codPers;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 10, max = 10)
    @Column(name = "E0497_NRODOM", nullable = false)
    private Integer nroDom; 

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 1)
    @Column(name = "E0497_FECH_INI", nullable = false)
    private Date fechIni;

    @Size(min = 10, max = 10)
    @Column(name = "E0497_FECH_FIN", nullable = false)
    private Timestamp fechFin;


    @Size(min = 2, max = 2)
    @Column(name = "E0497_CAL_DOM", nullable = false)
    private String calDom;

    @Size(min = 18, max = 18)
    @Column(name = "E0497_MATCKPRT", nullable = false)
    private String matckprt;

    @Size(min = 2, max = 2)
    @Column(name = "E0497_INFSRCTP", nullable = false)
    private String infsrctp;

    @Size(min = 2, max = 2)
    @Column(name = "E0497_TIPBUZON", nullable = false)
    private String tipBuzon;

    @Size(min = 10, max = 10)
    @Column(name = "E0497_FEC_EFEC", nullable = false)
    private Date fecEfec;

    @Size(min = 4, max = 4)
    @Column(name = "E0497_DETAL_CP", nullable = false)
    private String detalCp;

    @Size(min = 8, max = 8)
    @Column(name = "E0497_USULTACT", nullable = false)
    private String usultact;

    @Size(min = 4, max = 4)
    @Column(name = "E0497_EMULTACT", nullable = true)
    private String emultact;

    @Size(min = 4, max = 4)
    @Column(name = "E0497_CEULTACT", nullable = true)
    private String ceultact;

    @Size(min = 10, max = 10)
    @Column(name = "E0497_FEULTACT", nullable = true)
    private Date feultact;

    @Size(min = 8, max = 8)
    @Column(name = "E0497_HOR_ULTA", nullable = true)
    private Time horulta;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 26, max = 26)
    @Column(name = "E0497_TIMALTA", nullable = false)
    private Timestamp timAlta;

    /* Foreign key for HIS_DOMIC_INT table */  

    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_HIS_DOM_INT_ENTITY") // Por ejemplo
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private HisDomicIntEntity hisDomicInt;
}
```

con el uniqueConstraints consigues mantener la unicidad dentro de la tabla de la que sería la clave primaria que tienes en estos momentos, y podrías hacer los joins con la columna id, que resulta mucho mas sencillo de hacer y de entender después.